# radio button - align background image and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm having a problem align my custom radio button and text (see image)
[image]

I've use css for my radio buttons and can't seem to align them . 
here's my HTML :

```css
label.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
label.item > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
label.item > .radio-image::before {
  content: url("../tools/unchecked.png");


}
label.item > input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-image::before {
  content: url("../tools/checked.png");
}
label.item > input[type="radio"]:hover + .radio-image::before{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" value="Good/Minor Flaws" name="size" required="required" /> 
      <div class="radio-image text-center">Good / Minor Flaws</div>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" value="Major Damage" name="size" required="required"/> 
      <div class="radio-image text-center">Major Damage </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h2q7y4uj/#&togetherjs=ADTFQvN22E

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with similar problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h2q7y4uj/#&togetherjs=ADTFQvN22E

Comment: added a similar jfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/h2q7y4uj/4/

```css
div.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div.item > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

div.item > .radio-image::before {
  content: url(http://via.placeholder.com/50x50);
}

div.item > input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-image::before {
  content: url(http://via.placeholder.com/51x51);
}

div.item > input[type="radio"]:hover + .radio-image::before {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.radio-image > span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="radio" value="Good/Minor Flaws" name="size" required="required" />
      <div class="radio-image text-center">
        <span>Good / Minor Flaws</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="radio" value="Major Damage" name="size" required="required" />
      <div class="radio-image text-center">
        <span>Major Damage</span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! this is what it want!. i have another question. how do i make it responsive for smaller devices.?

Comment: and i tried multiple radios , i added another set. and its out of line

Answer (score 0):

Just update following css code

```
.radio-image {
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 30px;
}

label.item>.radio-image::before {
           content: url("../tools/unchecked.png");
            float: left;
            line-height: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 5px;
 }
```